# Increase width of a specific column while converting pandas Dataframes to PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframes that I am trying to convert into a `pdf` by first converting it to html. While converting it to html, we have col_space property that helps set column width for all columns of the html table.

```
some_dataframe.to_html(os.path.abspath(html_output_file_path), index=False, border=1, col_space=100)
```

But my requirement is that I need to increase the width of a specific column only and not all columns present in the final `pdf`.
Is there a way that I can increase the width of a single column only?

Comment: I am not sure it is possible. What you can do is generate on the side a CSS file that handle that column width. Or directly add a `width` attribute to your `<th>` attribute for the right column in the html you generated by opening it again in python after you generate it first

Comment: @Mayeulsgc I have raised an issue under `pandas` github. Let's see if they can modify col_space to accept a dict or a list to modify a specific column only.

Comment: Can you please refer to the github issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can exploit [.style](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) properety, which provides high grain control over the looks of the resulting HTML. Some CSS knowledge is required, though:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pdfkit

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))], axis=1)
styles = [dict(selector='.col3', props=[('min-width', '300px')]), dict(selector='.data', props=[('min-width', '6em')])]
html = df.style.hide_index().set_table_styles(styles).set_table_attributes('border=3 cellspacing=0').render()

with open(os.path.abspath(html_output_file_path), 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)

pdfkit.from_string(html, os.path.abspath(pdf_output_file_path))
```

This will generate the following look:
[image]

Comment: This is only changing the column width in HTML file. When converting to pdf using `pdfkit`, the column size reduces again.

Comment: This is a problem with `pdfkit` settings. If you use another [tool](https://pdfcrowd.com/#convert_by_input) the output  PDF is as expected.

Comment: You can overcome it by only using `min-width` property, and not `column-width`. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can  do it

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': ['foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo', 'bar bar bar bar bar'],
             'number': [1, 2]})
df.style.set_properties(subset=['test'], **{'width': '300px'})
new_df=df.style.set_properties(subset=['testt'], **{'width': '300px'})
```

Render this and save to file

```
html_df = new_df.hide_index().render()
with open("new_df.html","w") as fp:
    fp.write(html_df)
```

Pdfkit or any similar library should do trick from now on